# How to make a single histogram from 3 columns in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

This is my first time using ggplot2. I have a table of 3 columns and I want to plot frequency distribution of all three columns in one figure. I have only used hist() before so I am a little lost on this ggplot2. Here is an example of my table. Tab separated table with 3 columns A,B,C headers.

```
A         B           C
1.38502   1.38502     -nan
0.637291  0.753084    1.55556
0.0155242 0.0164394   -nan
3.29355   1.15757     -nan
1.00254   1.10108     0.132039
0.0155424 0.0155424   nan
0.760261  0.681639    0.298851
1.21365   1.21365     -nan
1.216      1.22541    -nan
0.61317   0.738528    0.585657
0.618276  0.940312    0.820591
1.96779   1.31051     1.58609
0.725413  2.29621     1.78989
0.684681  0.67331     0.290221
```

I have used the following code by looking up similar posts but I end up with error.

```
library(ggplot2)

dnds <- read.table('dNdS_plotfile', header =TRUE)

ggplot(data=dnds, melt(dnds), aes_(value, fill = L1))+ 
        geom_histogram()
```

> ERROR:No id variables; using all as measure variables
>
> Error: Mapping should be created with aes() or aes_().

I am really lost on how to solve this error. I want one figure with three different colored histograms that do not overlap in my final figure. Please help me achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: The first "error" is a warning.  The second is an error, because you need to give the melted dataset to the `data` argument but you pass it to the second argument in `ggplot`, which is the `mapping` argument.

Comment: Do you want three overlaid (or something) histograms? One for `A`, `B`, and `C`, respectively, or just merge all three columns into a single vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you're looking for. I like to load the package tidyverse, which loads a bunch of helpful packages like ggplot2 and dplyr.

In *geom_histogram()*, you can specify the bindwidth of the histograms with the argument *binwidth()* or the number of bins with *bins()*. If you also want the bars to not be stacked you can use the argument *position = "dodge"*.

See the documentation here: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.table("YOUR_DATA", header = T)

graph <- data %>% 
  gather(category, value)

ggplot(graph, aes(x = value, fill = category)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Not a problem! Happy to help!